# The product image on desktop view is clickable but is not clickable on mobile with bigcommerce theme. - HTML & CSS

Tags: html, css, bigcommerce

With the bigcommerce theme Parts Warehouse Version: 2.3.0, When inspecting the code, we can see that the image is linked and can be clicked on.

```
<a class="image-link desktop" href="/personalized-light-when-name-farts-soy-candle/" data-event-type="product-click" style="min-height:274px !important">
            <img class="card-image primary lazyautosizes ls-is-cached lazyloaded" data-sizes="auto" src="https://cdn11.bigcommerce.com/s-mq9vagwpbr/images/stencil/500x659/products/175/2160/IMG_7735-1__27458.1607224129.jpg?c=1" data-src="https://cdn11.bigcommerce.com/s-mq9vagwpbr/images/stencil/500x659/products/175/2160/IMG_7735-1__27458.1607224129.jpg?c=1" alt="Personalized Light When Name Farts Soy Candle" title="Personalized Light When Name Farts Soy Candle" style="max-height: 274px !important; max-width: 274px;" sizes="274px">
          </a>
```

However, with mobile, the image is not clickable only the description will take me to the landing page. How can I make this clickable using CSS since we don't have access to the html. [Image attached.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nt5D8.png)

```
<a class="image-link mobile" href="#0" data-event-type="product-click" style="min-height:274px !important">
              <img class="card-image primary lazyload" data-sizes="auto" src="https://cdn11.bigcommerce.com/s-mq9vagwpbr/stencil/9dbb4970-c51e-0139-9ebe-126b458adb51/e/1951f4a0-ee43-0139-3960-3e6f4d448bc9/img/loading.svg" data-src="https://cdn11.bigcommerce.com/s-mq9vagwpbr/images/stencil/500x659/products/175/2160/IMG_7735-1__27458.1607224129.jpg?c=1" alt="Personalized Light When Name Farts Soy Candle" title="Personalized Light When Name Farts Soy Candle" style="max-height: 274px !important; max-width: 274px;">
            </a>
```

Would this be the cause of the problem as well? If so is it fixable?

```
#body .image-link.mobile {
    display: none!important;
}
```

would there be a code that can grab the link from a different class [Image attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jNy3j.png)

Would greatly appreciate some help with this one! Thank you in advance!

Comment: did you try to work it out? What did you achive?

Comment: Hi Sara! That code block definitely looks like it may be the cause. If you download your template files and open them up in a code editor, you can search all files for this to help locate and remove it. I'd recommend starting with that! :)